# Using Microsoft.AppCenter with Xamarin.Forms (Shared project) results in an exception (Android)

Tags: android, exception, xamarin.forms, shared

I start today with implementing Microsoft.AppCenter for Analytics and Crashes into my Apps. On two of them (which run with a PCL project an MvvmCross on Xamarin.Forms) it runs perfectly fine. Also it works on my Xamarin.Forms (shared) project on the iOS side. But the Android side on this project always fails with an exception on startup when I use the AppCenter.Start()-Call. If I remove this call, no exception happens.

```
01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): Probing '__android_log_print'.Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11

01-20 01:18:58.950 D/Mono    ( 1675): Found as '__android_log_print'.
01-20 01:18:58.962 I/MonoDroid( 1675): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes' threw an exception. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5077d3f1b65f0ebbab0ee71c2383ed9a2.AndroidCrashListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.Object.cs:30 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.AndroidCrashListener..ctor (Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes owner) [0x00000] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes..ctor () [0x00006] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes..cctor () [0x0000a] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-20 01:18:58.965 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.StaticGetterAdapterFrame[R] (System.Reflection.MonoProperty+StaticGetter`1[R] getter, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:334 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:390 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:392 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.GetServices (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] services) [0x00029] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00026] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Zelda.BotW.Map.App.OnStart () [0x00007] in H:\Repositories\Privat\hg\zelda-botw-map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\App.xaml.cs:67 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:254 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStateChanged>d__32.MoveNext () [0x0003b] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:325 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
[0:] AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes' threw an exception. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5077d3f1b65f0ebbab0ee71c2383ed9a2.AndroidCrashListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.Object.cs:30 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.AndroidCrashListener..ctor (Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes owner) [0x00000] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes..ctor () [0x00006] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes..cctor () [0x0000a] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.StaticGetterAdapterFrame[R] (System.Reflection.MonoProperty+StaticGetter`1[R] getter, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:334 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:390 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:392 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.GetServices (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] services) [0x00029] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00026] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Zelda.BotW.Map.App.OnStart () [0x00007] in H:\Repositories\Privat\hg\zelda-botw-map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\App.xaml.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:254 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStateChanged>d__32.MoveNext () [0x0003b] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:325 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStart>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00048] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:256 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
  at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:417e1a7f-be99-4185-a6c5-4b19f0fe22c6 (intptr,intptr). IsTerminating: False01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 

01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStart>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00048] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:256 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:35 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:81 
01-20 01:18:58.966 I/MonoDroid( 1675):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:417e1a7f-be99-4185-a6c5-4b19f0fe22c6 (intptr,intptr)
An unhandled exception occured.

[0:] AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes' threw an exception. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5077d3f1b65f0ebbab0ee71c2383ed9a2.AndroidCrashListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.Object.cs:30 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.AndroidCrashListener..ctor (Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes owner) [0x00000] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes..ctor () [0x00006] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes..cctor () [0x0000a] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.StaticGetterAdapterFrame[R] (System.Reflection.MonoProperty+StaticGetter`1[R] getter, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:334 
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:390 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:392 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.GetServices (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] services) [0x00029] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00026] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
  at Zelda.BotW.Map.App.OnStart () [0x00007] in H:\Repositories\Privat\hg\zelda-botw-map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\App.xaml.cs:67 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:254 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStateChanged>d__32.MoveNext () [0x0003b] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:325 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStart>d__27.MoveNext () [0x00048] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:256 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:417e1a7f-be99-4185-a6c5-4b19f0fe22c6 (intptr,intptr). IsTerminating: True
referenceTable GDEF length=814 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=47302 1
referenceTable GDEF length=808 1
referenceTable GSUB length=11364 1
referenceTable GPOS length=49206 1
referenceTable head length=54 1
referenceTable head length=54 101-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes' threw an exception. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5077d3f1b65f0ebbab0ee71c2383ed9a2.AndroidCrashListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.SoftwareNotion.BreathCompanion-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00114] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods..ctor (System.Type declaringType) [0x00064] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.GetConstructorsForType (System.Type declaringType) [0x0002c] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00032] in <e736913786c2475188869561ae512b72>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Java.Lang.Object..ctor () [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5749/ef47226b/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/android-26/mcw/Java.Lang.Object.cs:30 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.AndroidCrashListener..ctor (Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes owner) [0x00000] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.PlatformCrashes..ctor () [0x00006] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes..cctor () [0x0000a] in <d3350e6250834260a1674c2436994900>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.StaticGetterAdapterFrame[R] (System.Reflection.MonoProperty+StaticGetter`1[R] getter, System.Object obj) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:334 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0005f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:390 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[] index) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoProperty.cs:392 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.GetServices (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] services) [0x00029] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00026] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.Start (System.String appSecret, System.Type[] services) [0x00000] in <42dc73f55eb143199a75bb5cc912fc22>:0 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Zelda.BotW.Map.App.OnStart () [0x00007] in H:\Repositories\Privat\hg\zelda-botw-map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\Zelda.BotW.Map\App.xaml.cs:67 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Xamarin.Forms.Application.SendStart () [0x00000] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:254 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity+<OnStateChanged>d__32.MoveNext () [0x0003b] in D:\agent\_work\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:325 
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
01-20 01:18:59.765 E/mono-rt ( 1675):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-5/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:1
```

Can somebody tell me what I missed? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

My app ran with Android Version 4.0. After installing the Nuget Packages, clean your solution, rebuild solution and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone with the same problem: The minimum Android Version must be 4.1 or higher. It was 4.0.3 on the affected project before.